# How to display a .ipynb file on github?

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

I have a following problem. I have uploaded a .ipynb file to my github repository. However, github cannot display my code and writes "Sorry, something went wrong. Reload?". What might be a problem here, please?

[image]

Comment: Github can automatically render and display `.ipynb` files... when it works.

Comment: Is anyone still seeing this problem??    I personally have not had a problem with notebooks displaying on GitHub for approximately a year now.  I think perhaps GitHub finally fixed the issue.   Is anyone else still seeing the issue?

Answer (score 11):

The same issue happens to me sometimes, I think it is related to GitHub's backend, size of the file and network connection. However you can use https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/ and paste the link in it. this site is independent from GitHub but it will solve your problem.

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your file name is correct "name.ipynb", with no typos or special symbols, then it is not a problem you can fix. It's an issue on GitHub's end. Unfortunately there is no solution for this. You can report a bug to GitHub, try later, or alternatively open your notebook in Jupyter

```
jupyter notebook
```

command in cmd.

Answer (score 1):

I have been grappling with this issue for months.
I am convinced that this is purely a **GitHub.com** issue.

What I am seeing is that notebooks  **sometimes render fine, and sometimes do not**.

Whenever the notebooks fail with **"Sorry, something went wrong. Reload?"**, *the same notebook will be fine some time later*, where "some time later" can be anywhere from several minutes to several hours (up to maybe a day).   However that doesn't mean that it won't start failing again several hours after that.

I am convinced **GitHub.com** is hosting a service on their machines that is used to render notebooks, and that sometimes this service either gets into a bad state, or crashes; when that happens notebooks won't render until the service is bounced (or somehow has its "good" state restored).

Unfortunately the only way I could find to report bugs to GitHub.com is to email support@github.com or fill out the form at https://support.github.com/contact .  Furthermore, in my experience GitHub.com is not very responsive to bug reports, and it appears they do not have a public issue tracker either.

Perhaps if enough of us email **support@github.com** with this complaint, then they will make it a priority and fix the issue.

The fact that these notebooks **on GitHub.com** will render just fine if you **place the github.com url of the notebook into https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/ is futher evidence that the issue is with GitHub.com**

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/) a simple way to share Jupyter Notebooks. and enter path of file with extension `.ipynb` in github and it will take you url of notebook you can share it easy

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways to overcome this problem and I think I found it. You can render your notebooks by yourself automatically using [Github Actions & nbconvert] then view outputs with public HTML urls.

See my repository here: https://github.com/salihmarangoz/github_ci_nbconvert

This would be the simplest way until Github fixes rendering errors for notebooks.